# how to insert json Data into Sqlite DB in PhoneGap

Tags: jquery, json, sqlite, jquery-mobile, cordova

We tried to `JSON` data insert to `SqlLit`.We need `JSON` Data insert into `SqlLit`.So first we crate Table and then tried to Insert `JSON` valu in table but it's not work.So Please tell me what wrong in my code

```
function startup() {
alert("1");
    console.log("Starting up...");
      db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo",10485760);
    db.transaction(function(tx){
    alert("2");
         tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS HEADER_DATA');
          tx.executeSql("create table if not exists docs(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, language TEXT, cookie TEXT, host TEXT, control TEXT)");
    },function(tx,error){
    alert("3");
        console.log('tx error: ' + error);
    },function(){
    alert("4");
        console.log('tx success');
         insert();
    });
}
```

For Insert:--

```
function insert(){
alert("5");
var output = $('#output').text('Refreshing documentation...');
 //$("#docs").html("Refreshing documentation...");

 $.ajax({
            url: 'http://headers.jsontest.com/',
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
            alert("6");
                // iterate over data and save it to DB
                output.empty();

                $.each(data, function(i,item){ 
                alert("7");
                 tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO docs (id, language, cookie, host ,control) VALUES(' + item.id + ', "' + item.Accept-Language + '", "' + item.Cookie + '", "' + item.Host + '", "' + item.Cache-Control+'")');
        }); 

                    output.append(landmark);
                });


            },
            error: function (x, y, z) {
                alert(x.responseText);
            }
        });


}
my json :--

{
   "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8",
   "Cookie": "__hbblk_headersjsontestcom=0",
   "Host": "headers.jsontest.com",
   "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.65 Safari/537.36",
   "Via": "1.1 FFTMG",
   "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
   "Cache-Control": "max-age=0"
}
```

in my code table Creation success but when tried to insert data into table it's not worked .so Please give me any small example for JSON data insert into SqlLit DB.

Comment: parse and push it as object and while retriving use stringify

Comment: @MohammedImranN could you please elaborated this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i see maybe the error was in the json handler.

try using something like this:

```
$.support.cors=true;                        // this two allow you to ask page outside ypur phone
$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;      //
$.getJSON('http://headers.jsontest.com/?callback=?',function(data){
    $.each(data, function(i, dat){
        $("#someul").append('<li>'+dat.rep+'</li>');  //i send data in json using rep as index
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for reply we are faced problem when json data insert into SqlLit Database so Please help me give me small example about my problem

Comment: I think that is an error defining the id column like this " id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT" because autoincrement modify the default behaviour.  Since you in your code set the id try without AUTOINCREMENT.  https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html